# How to show that this function is one-one with out graphing

Tags: calculus, functions

When solving a question, I had simplified an equation to $\frac{1}{2^x-1}$ and this is apparantly one-one when looking at the solution, I would like to learn how to identify how this function is one-one. I am quite clueless sorry.

Comment: Idea is to show that if we start with $f(a)=f(b)$ then $a=b$ is the only valid conclusion in the domain of the function.  This would mean no two distinct inputs can have same output.

Comment: Right sir thank you so much , I should have done better googling this seems very standard.

Comment: So, to expand Anurag A's comment, start by assuming $\frac{1}{2^a - 1} = \frac{1}{2^b - 1}$. Then, start doing things to both sides of the equation, hopefully making it less complex. To start you off, take the reciprocal of both sides. Also, don't forget logarithms exist!

Comment: **Shortcut**: Given $A\subseteq \Bbb{R}$ and given a **continuous** function $f:A\to \Bbb{R}$, then $f$ is one-to-one if and only if $f$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing throughout its domain.  Therefore, if $f$ happens to be differentiable throughout its domain, then the problem reduces to checking if the derivative of $f$ is always positive or always negative, throughout its domain.  Note the (somewhat bizarre) complication of an inflection point, as evidenced in $f(x) = x^3$, where $f'(x) = 3x^2$, so that $f'(x) = 0$ at $(x = 0).$